# Algorithm to generate the growth of a plant

Tags: javascript, genetic-algorithm

i'm crazy about plants and i'd like to make a small widget for my desktop to simulate a plant which would grow in realtime .

**The fact is i'm not that good at designing algorithms and i don't know where to start to be able to simulate my plant growth from the seed to an adult plant.**

the simulation should be able to generate branch, section and finally flower.

I would like to start with a very common plant such as a geranium .

i plan to develop it in JS with threejs ( threejs.org )

Comment: Where is the question ?

Comment: The question: what is the good start to code the growth of a plant ? i bolded it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could draw some inspiration from the fibonacci sequence.

Vi Hart has a really nice video on this topic (3 video series):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahXIMUkSXX0

Comment: Wonderful video and channell, awesome find!